# Scala: Sending response code for Rest services

Tags: scala, web-services, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a controller similar to below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(Array("/x/hello"))
class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private val helloService: HelloService = null

    var helloRequest: Option[HelloRequest] = _

    @RequestMapping
    def world: Option[HelloRequest] = {
              helloService.worldInstances
     }
```

worldInstances returns an instance of Option[HelloRequest] when the request is successful with 200 status code.

Now when something is wrong worldInstances sends a message of type Option[HelloRequest].
In this case I want a customised status code(say 400 which is not same as http status code of 400-Bad Request) instead of 200. (The response it sends is of the same format either it is successful or not but just the status code has to differ)

How can I explicitly set a status code in this case?

Comment: Does the controller automatically encode the response to json?

Comment: Please see the edited question. The response is of type DaasRequest

Answer (score 0):

In spring-mvc you have `@ExceptionHandler` or `@ControllerAdvice`, you throw exception and in the exceptionHandler you decide what to do:

for ref you can look at: [link](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)